# print texto despues de una arroba

Tags: php, echo

con que comando puedo separar el dominio de un correo

ejemplo:

```
$correo = 'xyz@eldominio.com';
```

necesito hacer un echo y el resultado sea el dominio solamente sin el @ sin importar lo que este escrito antes del @

he intentado con esto pero no me funciona:

```
 $correo = 'xyz@eldominio.com';
$resultado = preg_match_all('/\@[A-Za-z]+/', $correo);
    echo $resultado;
```

el resultado debe de ser solamente el dominio: **eldominio.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función explode() de PHP:

```
$correo = 'xyz@eldominio.com';
$dominio = explode("@", $correo);

echo $dominio[1];
```

Te dará 'dominio.com'

Comment: Estaría bien asegurarse de que el valor del correo contiene la @, para evitar posible error Undefined index al intentar usar $dominio[1].

Answer (score 0):

Sin usar regex, otra forma puede ser con [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) que dice la posición de la ocurrencia de un substring.

```
echo substr($correo, strpos($correo, '@')+1); // eldominio.com
```

Obviamente pasarán cadenas como usuarios de twitter o correos invalidos con multiples @, por lo que podrías antes hacer una validación del correo, el mismo problema lo tendrías con regex. Entonces:

```
if(filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo substr($correo, strpos($correo, '@')+1);
} else {
    echo 'No es un correo valido';
}
```